# Website is down but only for me

Tags: domain-name-system, connection, website

I have a website that is working fine for everyone but throws an error whenever I try and access it.

The web developer is saying it is a problem with my network. What should I check to confirm this?

I have tried via different internet connections and it always works on them.

I have tried using google's DNS server 8.8.8.8 and website still doesn't load.

If I ping the domain name, it returns the correct IP of the webserver.

The error I get is either a timeout or Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Does "ping" or "tracert" respond correctly?

Comment: @LatinSuD He has mentioned that he can ping the domain name. Tracert should work then also.

Comment: @Proxy That is incorrect. Ping and traceroute use two separate ICMP types.

Comment: @EEAA Valid, but it was a presumption that if ping worked, then all ICMP was permitted since OP did not mention anything in regards to ICMP(11/30) being blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Either your IP is blocked from the external web-service, and you cannot circumvent this directly without going through a VPN or proxy. You could check to see if you have not directly blocked it yourself in whatever browser you are using (I assume Chrome). You could also force the port, I.e: https://www.myhost.com:443/ or http://www.myhost.com:80/

Additionally, if you are using Chrome, try Incognito/Cleaning your browser to avoid invalid cookies or something along those lines which might prevent you from connecting.

If you require a username and password to login to that website, try Incognito to make sure nothing is caching.

Comment: I have tried with a clean browser cache no difference, but hadn't though of incognito mode (made no difference though)
Using a webproxy http://www.webproxy.net/ did allow me to load the page

Comment: So, if the proxy allowed you to connect, then your IP is blacklisted potentially, as you took the proxy's IP to access the webpage. Depending on your current IP setup, restarting your home router sometimes resets your dynamic IP (unless your ISP gives you a static IP) which will allow you to access the webpage again. Alternatively, contact the site owner to say your IP is dynamic and it is blocked in error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually that the webserver was blocking traffic from my IP only.

However the block was put in place because of traffic using port 389 from my IP. Port 389 is LDAP, so now I am wondering what would cause my network to send packets that use this port but that is another question I think.

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions about this.